# schroeder bernstein theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

schroeder bernstein theorem states that if there is an injective function from A to B and an injective function for  B to A then A is equivalent to B. If A and B are finite what does having a bijection function mean? If A and B are infinite then does it mean that A and B are countably infinite?

Comment: If means $\;|A|=|B|\;$ , as it says (no matter whether finite or infinite), and no: if $\;|A|, |B|\ge\aleph_0\;$ the theorem doesn't imply they must be countably infinite.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ are finite, the existence of a bijection means that they have the same number of elements.

If $A$ and $B$ are infinite, then it means they are the "same kind" of infinite. Possibly countable, but it doesn't have to be.